# Combining gsub() and using variable names as columns in R

Tags: r, loops, gsub

I'm hoping that someone can help me :)

I have a data frame with about 1000 columns.
Within that, I have columns named like this:
X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6 etc... Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5,Y6 etc...

```
df <- data.frame("X1" = c("Yes","No","Yes","NA","NA","NA","Yes","No","Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                "X2" = c("Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA","Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA","Yes","NA","NA"), 
                "X3" = c("Yes","NA","NA","NA","Yes","No","Yes","NA","Yes","NA","NA","NA", "Yes"),
                "X4" = c("Yes","No","Yes","NA","NA","NA","Yes","No","Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                "X5" = c("Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA","Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA","Yes","NA","NA"), 
                "X6" = c("Yes","NA","NA","NA","Yes","No","Yes","NA","Yes","NA","NA","NA", "Yes"),
                "Y1" = c("Yes","No","Yes","NA","NA","NA","Yes","No","Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                "Y2" = c("Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA","Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA","Yes","NA","NA"), 
                "Y3" = c("Yes","NA","NA","NA","Yes","No","Yes","NA","Yes","NA","NA","NA", "Yes"),
                "Y4" = c("Yes","No","Yes","NA","NA","NA","Yes","No","Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                "Y5" = c("Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA","Yes","NA","NA","NA","NA","Yes","NA","NA"), 
                "Y6" = c("Yes","NA","NA","NA","Yes","No","Yes","NA","Yes","NA","NA","NA", "Yes"))
```

In certain columns, I replace "Yes" with 1, and "No" with 0, and replace anything else with an NA.

I have tried this:

```
names = c("X","Y")

for (name in names){
  try(
    for (j in 1:6){
      j <- toString(j)
      colname <- paste(name , j, sep="")
      df$colname <- gsub("Yes", as.integer(1), df$colname)
      df$colname <- gsub("No", as.integer(0), df$colname)
    })}
```

However, this is not working, throwing error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "colname", value = character(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 13
```

- My first question is: Why are the column names not referencing properly?
- Second question is: How do I replace anything that's not a 0 or 1 in those columns with an "NA"?

This is possibly a really simple thing that I'm overlooking, but I can't quite figure out how to do it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,
Rich

Comment: For future reference, the `df$colname` is wrong. here you would need to use `df[, colname]`, and you also don't need quotes around variable names when creating the df in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a loop or gsub here, you can use this:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) x <- car::recode(x, "'Yes'=1; 'No'=0; 'NA'=NA"))
```

This iterates over each column in your dataframe and recodes the values as you want. This is also easier to expand if you get more values in the future.

If you only want certain columns, you can modify it like this:

```
df[, col_list] <- lapply(df[, col_list], function(x) x <- car::recode(x, "'Yes'=1; 'No'=0; 'NA'=NA"))
```

Where `col_list` is the vector of the variables you want to change. You could grep for them using `col_list <- grep('^X|Y', names(df), value = T)`

Comment: This is amazing, thank you.  How would I specify which columns to replace?  For example, I only need to loop through certain columns.   As there are a lot of columns though, I have opted to loop through as I have above.  Is there a better way?

Comment: yep, just added a bit on that

Comment: no worries, make sure to mark as accepted solution if this has resolved your problem

Comment: why not just use `factor`? `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.integer(factor(x, c('No', 'Yes'))) - 1)`

Comment: yeah thats probs better. i always forget factors have this property

Answer (score 0):

Since your data has only `'Yes'`, `'No'` and `'NA'` values you can also directly replace them.

```
#Column numbers to replace
cols <- grep('^[XY]\\d+', names(df))
#Replace "NA" with real NA
df[cols][df[cols] == 'NA'] <- NA
#Replace "Yes" with 1
df[cols][df[cols] == 'Yes'] <- 1
#Replace "No" with 0
df[cols][df[cols] == 'No'] <- 0
#Change dataframe type.
df <- type.convert(df)
df
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6
#1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#2   0 NA NA  0 NA NA  0 NA NA  0 NA NA
#3   1 NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA
#4  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#5  NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  1
#6  NA  1  0 NA  1  0 NA  1  0 NA  1  0
#7   1 NA  1  1 NA  1  1 NA  1  1 NA  1
#8   0 NA NA  0 NA NA  0 NA NA  0 NA NA
#9   1 NA  1  1 NA  1  1 NA  1  1 NA  1
#10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#11 NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA
#12 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#13 NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  1
```

If you are using R < 4.0.0, you first need to convert data into characters.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
```